# How to get cross-domain communication to work in iframes?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser

I have an iframe-based online help system that has worked well for years. With IE8 it chokes on some of the javascripting that calls location.toString(). This same code works fine in IE6.

Specifically, the code is:

```
var iss = parent.left.location.toString();
var isInd = iss.indexOf("indexframe");
```

I get a "permission denied" error. I believe the problem is related to cross-domain communications, which I'm not sure I fully understand. The whole package runs locally using local HTML and javascript files. I'm not trying to have a frame in one domain control a frame in another domain. Or maybe I'm way off base in assuming this is the problem.

Could someone help me to understand what I need to do to work around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the iFrame and the parent Document are in the same domain then you should not get that error. It suggests to me that the documents are in different domains.

If the Iframe is in *www.mydomain.com* and the document is in *help.mydomain.com* YOU WILL GET AN ERROR! The pages must think they are in the exact same domain.

In both documents you could add javascript the set the domain:

```
document.domain = "mydomain.com";
```

Javascript will allow you to drop into the host domain on both pages. This allows you to communicate accross the frames. Of course if the pages are in different HOST domains then this won't work and javascript will throw the error.

Comment: Yes. This is what is bugging me too. I am running the whole shebang locally and all files are local. I don't understand why IE8 sees things as running from different domains.

Comment: Running local? As in from "file://"? Nope, that won't work. IE has completely different security restrictions for files run locally. You'll need to run through a web server and over http:// try IIS express or cassini

Comment: Not sure I understand. Why can't I create a Help system where all the HTML help files run locally inside an iFrame? The left panel is a TOC that causes the right panel to open the correct HTML file. It worked fine in IE6 on WinXP.

Comment: For security reasons they have really locked down what you can do locally. Also, it's hard to determine the "domain" of documents coming from the file system. It's explained here: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2004/08/20/218123.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Typically when accessing the content of another iframe, i use something like this:

```
var f = document.getElementById('IdOfIFrame'), 
    d = f.contentDocument||f.contentWindow;
alert(d.location);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are indeed accessing 2 domains from your site, *and* you own both of them, you can create an xml file that specifies which domains should be allowed to share.  See [the spec document](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html).  This opt-in cross-site access is supported by more than just Adobe (MS Silverlight for one). Here is Silverlight's [support spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28VS.95%29.aspx).

Comment: I'm running on a laptop. My domain should be localhost. All HTML files being pulled into the frames are in the same folder as the index.html file, which is setting up the iframe.